# How to get back Magento from server

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

My client had a website with Magento CMS and he has left it from 2 years, now he wants to get back the website, all what he has is username and password to login into magento, and the host, now i want to know if i can install Magento locally and debug it to get all source code of the site and database with only this informations ?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the admin login to the magento you can do a Back up from the admin To take the store offline during thebackup process, set Maintenance Mode to “Yes.” On the Admin menu, select System > Magento Connect >Magento Connect Manager. Select the Create Backup checkbox and select the backup type. If you have the hosting information you can back up the mysql or whatever database and import it into your local install. Just make sure you update the table to correspond with your installation tables.

Comment: Ok thank you i did it, but i don't know for the source code of the site web how to get it. And if i want also to regain control to Magento in server and debug it can i do it ?

Comment: You can take the backup and that should be good. Make sure you take a full backup. You can also save the theme. It's in the admin file manager. Would be great if you had ftp. You could grab the theme and replicate on local.

Comment: can you tell me how to have ftp ? maybe i can get it by website link ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Always waiting for response ;(

Comment: Most hosts offer ftp so copy all filed in the public_html. Backup will be saved in backs or /var/backups